# NavigationUrl with in line appSettings:***

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I'm having issues with my NavigationUrl,  basically if I wasn't storing the web address in the web config file this would be easy but it doesn't appear that you can call appSettings:SFL in line, does any one know of a soulution

```html
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format(appSettings:SFL+"{0}\\{1}", Eval("H_CN_NO"), Eval("H_LNK").ToString() ) %>' Target="_blank" Text='<%# Eval("H_LNK") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are storing the address in the web.config? You can use the ~ to get the base url of your site and add location of the page after.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" Text="Home" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

This could also be set in the code behind

```
HyperLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Default.aspx;
```